# I am getting error in pod install using react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, cocoapods

#### Command

```
/usr/local/bin/pod install
```

#### Report

- What did you do?
- What did you expect to happen?
- What happened instead?

#### Stack

```
   CocoaPods : 1.9.3
        Ruby : ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [universal.x86_64-darwin19]
    RubyGems : 3.0.3
        Host : Mac OS X 10.15.4 (19E287)
       Xcode : 11.2.1 (11B500)
         Git : git version 2.23.0
Ruby lib dir : /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib
Repositories : trunk - CDN - https://cdn.cocoapods.org/
```

#### Plugins

```
cocoapods-deintegrate : 1.0.4
cocoapods-plugins     : 1.0.0
cocoapods-search      : 1.0.0
cocoapods-stats       : 1.1.0
cocoapods-trunk       : 1.4.1
cocoapods-try         : 1.1.0
```

#### Podfile

```rb
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'OCR' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for OCR

  target 'OCR-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'OCRTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end

target 'OCR-tvOS' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for OCR-tvOS

end
```

#### Error

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `files' for <PBXFileReference path=`Pods` UUID=`B3A7587E24F0739000423517`>:Xcodeproj::Project::Object::PBXFileReference
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/user_project_integrator/target_integrator/xcconfig_integrator.rb:165:in `create_xcconfig_ref'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/user_project_integrator/target_integrator/xcconfig_integrator.rb:45:in `set_target_xcconfig'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/user_project_integrator/target_integrator/xcconfig_integrator.rb:21:in `block (2 levels) in integrate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/user_project_integrator/target_integrator/xcconfig_integrator.rb:20:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/user_project_integrator/target_integrator/xcconfig_integrator.rb:20:in `block in integrate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/user_project_integrator/target_integrator/xcconfig_integrator.rb:19:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/user_project_integrator/target_integrator/xcconfig_integrator.rb:19:in `integrate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/user_project_integrator/target_integrator.rb:399:in `block in integrate!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/user_project_integrator/target_integrator.rb:398:in `integrate!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/user_project_integrator.rb:146:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/user_project_integrator.rb:146:in `integrate_user_targets'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/user_project_integrator.rb:73:in `integrate!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:801:in `block in integrate_user_project'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:797:in `integrate_user_project'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:176:in `integrate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:162:in `install!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

[!] Oh no, an error occurred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found your issue in github ghttps://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/7395

Comment: My command is right. I am using this command.

cd your_project/ios 
pod install

But it's not working :-(

Comment: I found your issue in github ghttps://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/7395

Comment: Yes, this solution helped me to resolve the problem.

https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/7395
Thank you @anh-devit .